# field of struct is private when importing module

Tags: rust

I am trying to split my project into multiple files but I am having problems importing them into my `main.rs` as it says the Column's fields are private but I have declared the struct as public.

src/column.rs

```
pub struct Column {
    name: String,
    vec: Vec<i32>,
}
```

src/main.rs

```
pub mod column;

fn main() {
    let col = column::Column{name:"a".to_string(), vec:vec![1;10]};
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

cargo build

```
src/main.rs:4:15: 4:75 error: field `name` of struct `column::Column` is private
src/main.rs:4     let col = column::Column{name:"a".to_string(), vec:vec![1;10]};
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:4:15: 4:75 error: field `vec` of struct `column::Column` is private
src/main.rs:4     let col = column::Column{name:"a".to_string(), vec:vec![1;10]};
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try labeling the fields as public:

```
pub struct Column {
    pub name: String,
    pub vec: Vec<i32>,
}
```

Labeling `Column` as `pub` means that other modules can use the struct itself, but not necessarily all of its members.

Comment: Ahhh, ok. I assumed that using `pub struct` would make the struct's fields as that's the impression I got from the book.

Answer (score 22):

You've declared the struct as public, but not the fields. To make both fields public, the struct declaration should look as follows:

```
pub struct Column {
    pub name: String,
    pub vec: Vec<i32>,
}
```